# Enabling Ingress addons on minikube for Kong

Tags: minikube, kong, kong-ingress

I am following [this](https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/2.10.x/guides/getting-started/) to configure Kong Ingress controller(KIC) on minikube. I created ingress for my backend service as told in the link. But when I see details of the ingress created, ADDRESS is empty.

So based on Stack Overflow answers, I need to run

> minikube addons enable ingress

But when do I run it? Should I run it before I execute the KIC command:

> minikube kubectl create -f
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/v2.10.0/deploy/single/all-in-one-dbless.yaml

Answer (score 1):

For transparency I'm a maintainer of kong addon for minikube
Minikube includes a native kong addon

Check the official doc
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/addons/kong-ingress/

Note in order to access your services you need to install metalb addon or use minikube tunnel (explained in the doc)

Comment: Thanks. I couldnt find this information on official documentation https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/latest/guides/getting-started/. And I did 'minikube addons enable ingress' based on various SO answers. BTW, can that be the reason that all my service endpoints are responding same content(some metadata)?

Comment: You don't need minikube addons enable Ingress. It will use nginx for Ingress.

Comment: minikube addons enable kong will do the thing. Take a look at the minikube doc Iinked in the answer. Hope it helps

Comment: 'minikube addons enable kong' clashes with https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/v2.10.0/deploy/single/all-in-one-dbless.yaml.

Comment: You don't need to manually install kong ingress via yaml when using the addon.

Comment: But that yaml has definitions for other resources like KongConsumer, KongPlugin etc.  which are needed for my work.